# how to create story book in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

I want to make iphone story book application.
I want to use animation.
Please help me

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your question needs to be specific to a particular programming problem or issue that can be described in detail or shown with sample code, otherwise you might get answers like:

Use the UIStoryBookView and when you initialise it pass TRUE to initWithAnimation:

```
UIStoryBookView * redRidingHood = [[UIStoryBookView alloc] initWithAnimation:TRUE];
```

Comment: good one. wish i could upvote this 10 times for a nice answer :).